# Ranma 1/2 Season 7, Ep. 151, The Kuno Sibling Scandal - Score

Tags: music, ranma

Adorable, goofy song. 
Could someone tell me what the song is at around 7:04, where Kuno Tatewaki jumps Ranma to reclaim his album of girl-Ranma pics, on the bridge with Kodachi? It's hilarious.

Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sLnwCZuYCnE

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Found it!

34:03 -35:46 Kenji Kawai - Come Back Here! [Chuugoku Nekonron Daikessen! Okite Yaburi No Geki]

Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BvSHGaoP43c